# display field name as column and field value as row in sql server

Tags: sql-server

i have table with column FieldName, Field Value

with Data

```
    forms_data_id   fk_forms_id formcount   fieldname   fieldvalue  createddate
1   1   0   State   Alabama 2017-06-20 10:35:07.300
2   1   0   City    ahmedabad   2017-06-20 10:35:07.317
3   1   0   Zip 380061  2017-06-20 10:35:07.333
4   1   0   Gender  Male    2017-06-20 10:35:07.347
5   1   0   Job Developer   2017-06-20 10:35:07.363
6   1   0   IsActive    0   2017-06-20 10:35:07.380
7   1   0   Lastname    1234    2017-06-20 10:35:07.393
8   1   0   Firstname   1234    2017-06-20 10:35:07.410
```

,
 i want result as under

```
FirstName  LastName Gender
Ram         Mehta   Male
Shyam       Mehra   Male
```

But my issue is Field Name is not fixed. i can be 5 or 10 more.

I Need MSSQL Query to achieve result as Above

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Unfortunately your post is lacking any kind of detail needed for others to help. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Hope now it will look like good.

Comment: Given your data there is absolutely no way to know what rows belong to a given person. I could easily produce your desired output from the sample but once there is a second person it is impossible.

Comment: this is challenge sir, because its dynamic for, i have Query in mysql but i didnt find any query for MSSQL to produce this Result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this. It will work for you.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VIEW_YOURTABLE] AS
SELECT 
FieldName
,FieldValue
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FieldName ORDER BY FieldValue ASC) AS RN
FROM YOUR_TABLE

DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns += N', ' + QUOTENAME(FieldName)
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT FieldName FROM VIEW_YOURTABLE
  ) AS x;
SET @sql = N'SELECT ' 
+ STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') 
+ 'FROM
(

SELECT RN, FieldName, FieldValue FROM VIEW_YOURTABLE

) AS j PIVOT
(
  MAX(FieldValue) FOR FieldName IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', [', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS p ORDER BY p.RN;';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: hello sir. there is problem its return me Error "Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 44
The column 'State' was specified multiple times for 'p'.
" where 2 or more record are there

Comment: If there are 2 or more record. How do you want to do?

Comment: If there are 2 or more record same then only get one record. I've edited.

Comment: no sir, its display in one row with column like city 1, city 2, firstname 1 , firstname 2

Comment: There are 2 city, firstname, How do you want to show?

Comment: i want to show like field name should be display one time as column and field value will be as row.

Comment: sir , any chance to complete this one ??

Comment: I'm sorry, I am thinking to solve it. Now there are not any way.

Comment: Can you create view?

Comment: i can create anything sir, i just want solutions.

Comment: now row display data with comman separated like in first name its display x,y and gender its display male,male but its its display data in 1 row only. we need multipal row

Comment: Take picture your data and your result. I got off work today. I will reply you tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Still not totally clear what you want here but you can use a cross tab (aka conditional aggregation) for this type of thing.

Notice how I posted your sample data so it is readily consumable for others. You should do this in the future to make it easier for people helping.

```
DECLARE @Something TABLE
(
    forms_data_id INT
    , fk_forms_id INT
    , formcount INT
    , fieldname VARCHAR(50)
    , fieldvalue VARCHAR(50)
    , createddate DATETIME
)

INSERT @Something
(
    forms_data_id,
    fk_forms_id,
    formcount,
    fieldname,
    fieldvalue,
    createddate
)
VALUES
(1, 1, 0, 'State', 'Alabama', '2017-06-20 10:35:07.300'), 
(2, 1, 0, 'City', 'ahmedabad', '2017-06-20 10:35:07.317'), 
(3, 1, 0, 'Zip', '380061', '2017-06-20 10:35:07.333'), 
(4, 1, 0, 'Gender', 'Male', '2017-06-20 10:35:07.347'), 
(5, 1, 0, 'Job', 'Developer', '2017-06-20 10:35:07.363'), 
(6, 1, 0, 'IsActive', '0', '2017-06-20 10:35:07.380'), 
(7, 1, 0, 'Lastname', '1234', '2017-06-20 10:35:07.393'), 
(8, 1, 0, 'Firstname', '1234', '2017-06-20 10:35:07.410')

SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN fieldname = 'Firstname' THEN fieldvalue END) AS FirstName
    , MAX(CASE WHEN fieldname = 'Lastname' THEN fieldvalue END) AS LastName
    , MAX(CASE WHEN fieldname = 'Gender' THEN fieldvalue END) AS Gender
FROM @Something s
GROUP BY s.fk_forms_id
```

---

Here is another way to tackle this. This is using a dynamic cross tab. I find this preferable to the dynamic pivot because for me the syntax is less obtuse. I first have to switch from a table variable to a temp table.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Something
GO

CREATE table #Something
(
    forms_data_id INT
    , fk_forms_id INT
    , formcount INT
    , fieldname VARCHAR(50)
    , fieldvalue VARCHAR(50)
    , createddate DATETIME
)

INSERT #Something
(
    forms_data_id,
    fk_forms_id,
    formcount,
    fieldname,
    fieldvalue,
    createddate
)
VALUES
(1, 1, 0, 'State', 'Alabama', '2017-06-20 10:35:07.300'), 
(2, 1, 0, 'City', 'ahmedabad', '2017-06-20 10:35:07.317'), 
(3, 1, 0, 'Zip', '380061', '2017-06-20 10:35:07.333'), 
(4, 1, 0, 'Gender', 'Male', '2017-06-20 10:35:07.347'), 
(5, 1, 0, 'Job', 'Developer', '2017-06-20 10:35:07.363'), 
(6, 1, 0, 'IsActive', '0', '2017-06-20 10:35:07.380'), 
(7, 1, 0, 'Lastname', '1234', '2017-06-20 10:35:07.393'), 
(8, 1, 0, 'Firstname', '1234', '2017-06-20 10:35:07.410')
```

Now with a temp table we can do this a little differently.

```
declare @StaticPortion nvarchar(2000) = 
    'with OrderedResults as
    (
        select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by fk_forms_id order by fieldname) as RowNum
        from #Something
    )
    select fk_forms_id';

declare @DynamicPortion nvarchar(max) = '';
declare @FinalStaticPortion nvarchar(2000) = ' from OrderedResults Group by fk_forms_id order by fk_forms_id';

select @DynamicPortion = @DynamicPortion + 
    ', MAX(Case when RowNum = ' + CAST(N as varchar(6)) + ' then fieldvalue end) as ' + Cols.fieldname --+ CAST(N as varchar(6)) + CHAR(10)
from cteTally t
JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT fieldname
        , forms_data_id
    FROM #Something s
) Cols ON Cols.forms_data_id = t.N
where t.N <= 
(
    select top 1 Count(*)
    from #Something
    group by fk_forms_id
    order by COUNT(*) desc
)

select @StaticPortion + @DynamicPortion + @FinalStaticPortion

declare @SqlToExecute nvarchar(max) = @StaticPortion + @DynamicPortion + @FinalStaticPortion;
exec sp_executesql @SqlToExecute
```

Comment: My Fields are not limited to 3 it can be more like 5 to 10 or 15. as form is dynamic

Comment: So you want all columns output then not just the ones you listed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cross-tab to generate such result.

Suppose you got a table like:

**Name   Salary** 
Mark     3000 
David    4000 
Kyal      15000 
Jhon     10000

Then below query can generate result shown below:

SELECT [Mark], [David], [Kyal], [Jhon] 
FROM 
( SELECT Name, Salary 
    FROM EmpSalary ) AS MainTable 
**PIVOT** 
( 
SUM(Salary) 
FOR Name IN ([Mark], [David], [Kyal], [Jhon]) 
) AS PT;

Output:

**Mark     David      Kyal   Jhon** 

3000   4000   15000      10000

Hope that's what you wanted to achieve.

Manoj.